# Investment Company-Btc wallet btc transfer

Tags: fraud

Okay, I have US$41,000 BTC sent from the company
It was heading to my crypto wallet

I had a cell phone call from someone claiming to be from Blockchain

They claim that I have to pay 10% deposit because they have stopped the payment. They mention the company name they mention the amount being sent to me.

They contacted me by phone number

He said I had to get the 10% in BTC and send it to the wallet in question after I get my 41,000 in BTC, as it is over the $25k limit only imposed last week:- the 10% would be refunded back to my wallet. Meanwhile its pending…

Is this correct

Comment: No it's not. You got scammed. You lost your money. Do NOT send them any more. NO matter what they say. You will only lose more.

Answer (score 1):

Anyone who claims that they owe you money but that you must pay some money in order to get it is scamming you. Any legitimate company would gladly deduct any money you need to pay from the money that they admit that they owe you.

You do not have $41,000. There is nothing heading to your wallet. Nothing is pending. Everyone you are interacting with is part of a scam.

Anyone who claims they can help you get any money out of them is also trying to scam you. There is no money to get from them. The funds you are chasing simply do not exist.